# Get items with Rails relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models with a relation like this:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :group
end
```

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
 has_many :tickets, as: :assignable
end
```

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :tickets, -> { order(:created_at) }
 has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

I need to get all tickets belonging to the same groups the user has.
How can I accomplish that? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As things stand, your relations are incomplete and so Rails won't work properly. If User `has_many` Tickets then Tickets must `belong_to` (or at least `has_one`) User. Alternatively, User can `have_many` Tickets `through` Group, which seems more likely in this case.

However, even then, it's not clear what your Group model is doing. Particularly, it's not clear how you intend it to relate to User - this looks like quite a complex relationship.

To start with, though, try and set the models up like this:

```rb
class Ticket < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :group
end

class Group < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 has_many :tickets, dependent: :destroy
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :groups, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :tickets, through: :groups
end
```

(You'll see that I've also inherited these models from ApplicationRecord, which is how I've always done it.)

If you set it up as above, you can get your ticket records with a simple `@user.tickets`.

If this works, you can then add the extra HABTM relationship for Groups and Users. But be aware that HABTM relationships can be complex and there are good and bad ways to use them.

(If the primary relationship you really want is Groups > Users > Tickets then let me know and I can adjust accordingly.)

Comment: ApplicationRecord was introduced in Rails 5. Previous versions would generate models that inherited directly from ActiveRecord::Base and you need to create the ApplicationRecord class which is usually one the steps you do when upgrading legacy apps.

Comment: Thanks for that @max - given I started with Rails 5, that'll explain it!

Comment: I really appreciate your help, thank you!
I updated the post with the model that was missing.
Unfortunately, when I do @user.tickets I don't get the desired result because it only returns the tickets created by the current user.
I would like to get all tickets that have the same user group but that may have been created by another user. It is a little complicated =/

Comment: In that case, you need `@group.tickets`. Rails provides helpers like this for all relationships - provided you define the relationships between your models properly, Rails will help you out!